# Firestore returns insufficient permissions, even tough it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the following rules set up for my Firestore database:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /collections/{document=**} {
        allow read;
        allow write: if isAdmin();
        }

    match /general/{document=**} {
        allow read;
        allow write: if isAdmin();
        }

    match /inquiries/{document=**} {
        allow write;
        allow read: if isAdmin();
        }

    match /orders/{document=**} {
        allow write;
        allow read: if isAdmin() || resource.data.userID == request.auth.uid;
        }

    match /products/{document=**} {
        allow read;
        allow write: if isAdmin();
        }

    match /users/{userId} {
        allow write, read: if belongsTo(userId);
        }

    function belongsTo(userId) {
        return request.auth.uid == userId
        }

    function isAdmin() {
        return resource.data.admin == true;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, everybody is allowed to read /products and its documents plus subcollections. Which works for the products, **but somehow the product's subcollection (every product has one called `collection-colors`) can't be read.**

> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Code causing the error:

```
retrieveCollectionColors(name) {
    this.db.collectionGroup('collection-colors', ref => ref.where('product', '==', name))
      .valueChanges().subscribe( (val: []) => {
      this.collectionColors.next(val);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the specific code that isn't working the way you expect.  We should be able to compare the query with the rules to see if you did anything wrong on either end.

Comment: @DougStevenson You're right, sorry. Updated the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rules you have right now don't apply at all to collection group queries.  You'll need to write a special rule for that.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups):

> **Secure and query documents based on collection groups**
>
> In your security rules, you must explicitly allow collection group
>   queries by writing a rule for the collection group:
>
> - Make sure rules_version = '2'; is the first line of your ruleset. Collection group queries require the new recursive wildcard `{name=**}`
>     behavior of security rules version 2.
> - Write a rule for you collection group using `match /{path=**}/[COLLECTION_ID]/{doc}`.

So, if you want to allow collection group queries for "collection-colors", it will look something like this:

```
match /{path=**}/collection-colors/{doc} {
  allow read: ...
}
```

This will apply to **all** subcollections with the given name.  You can't selectively allow or disallow subcollections based on the name of the parent collection.